# grep recursively in ksh on AIX

Tags: grep, recursive

How do I `grep` recursively in directories and sub directories in `ksh` on `AIX`?

I have tried `grep -r` but this is not available.

Answer (score 0):

`grep -R` R is uppercase, not lowercase. By the way, grep is not related to the shell, it is a command of its own.

Comment: I have tried with upper case as well, but no luck

Comment: It works for us on our AIX 6.1 maybe your grep is outdated.

Comment: You have a workaround in the next link http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=273108 basically the command is `find /path/to/search | xargs grep re-to-use`

Comment: I'm not sure why this was duplicated.
The linked question is different, does not address AIX and does not offer a working solution. 
I have AIX 7.1.0.0 and neither grep -r or -R function recursively. 

What does work, if you are trying to locate a pattern in files of file_type:
grep "pattern"  \`find . -name "file_type"\`