# grep or find a pattern in all directories

Tags: grep, find, ksh, aix

I have an account number `1234-5678`, I am trying to find it in all files of directories. I used the below command but no result found.

`grep "1234-5678" */`

Please can someone help me how to find it in all files of directories.

Comment: Use the `-r, --recursive` switch of `grep`.

Comment: `grep "1234-5678" * -r` or `grep "1234-5678" * -R`

Comment: Did you not [ask that same question just 3 weeks ago](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/189198/22565)? What's wrong with the answers you got there? What version of AIX are you using?

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas sorry i have forgot about that, so i posted this.

Comment: For your penance, can you please go and double-check if AIX's `grep -R` searches in fifos, devices or the target of symlinks? `mkdir X; ln -s /etc/issue X/a; mkfifo X/b; grep -R . X` and see if it hangs or matches on /etc/issue.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas yes i have checked that `grep -R` is not working on my machine

Comment: What version of AIX?

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas I am using the `AIX 5.2`

Comment: Yes, I've just double checked those -r/-R were added in 5.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Portably/standardly:

```
find . -type f -exec grep 1234-5678 /dev/null {} +
```

Some `grep` implementations have `-r` or `-R` options to search in files recursively. The behaviour varies from implementation to implementation though.

With the [`grep` found in AIX 6.1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/grep.htm) for instance, you'll probably want to use the [`-R` option](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.cmds2/grep.htm#grep__row-d3e144140)<sup>1</sup>.

Beware though that contrary to the `find` approach above, it may look in non-regular files like fifos or device files (or may not, I don't have access to an AIX system just now).

<sub><sup>1</sup> Support for those -r/-R options was added in AIX 5.3 according to IBM's online documentation. And it should be noted that the meaning of -r/-R is the reverse from that of GNU grep (-r follows symlinks to directories, and -R doesn't while it's the contrary with GNU grep)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

`grep "1234-5678" * -r` or `grep "1234-5678" * -R` if you want to follow the symbolic links.

Comment: Having options after arguments is a GNUism and will typically not fork in non-GNU systems like the OP's AIX. Also note that the meaning of -r/-R is reversed between GNU and AIX greps. You command may not work if there are file names that start with `-`. It will also exclude hidden files and dirs in the current directory, but not in sub-directories.

Comment: Then (s)he can use your solution ;-) Good explanation BTW.